# binning the numbers with wrong outcome

Tags: r, cut, binning

I have problems with the output after I bin the a numerical vector.

I am trying to bin the length of stay, which was calculated beforehand with difftime function. It does not make sense to provide the whole code since this is only the background. Yet, when I bin, I do not get the right answer.
Here is the length of stay assigned it with los.

```
dput(los)
c(61.0416666666667, 61.0416666666667, 61.0416666666667, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

Here are my breaks. I used na.rm inside as tried several methods. I passed na.rm with TRUE, FALSE and took it out of my breaks.

```
breaks <- c(0, 0.8, 0.16, 
           1.0, 1.8, 1.16, 
           2.0, 2.8, 2.16, 
           3.0, 3.8, 3.16, 
           4.0, 4.8, 4.16, 
           5.0, 5.8, 5.16, 
           6.0, 6.8, 6.16, 
           7.0, 14.0, 21.0, 28.0, max(los)) #, , na.rm = FALSE
```

Nevertheless, the next code tried

```
dt_los$losbinned <- cut(dt_los$LOS, 
                         breaks = breaks,
                         labels = c("0hrs", "8hrs", "16hrs", "1 d", 
                                 "1 d 8hrs", "1 d 16hrs", "2 d", 
                                 "2 d 8hrs", "2 d 16hrs", "3 d", 
                                 "3 d 8hrs", "3 d 16hrs", "4 d", 
                                 "4 d 8hrs", "4 d 16hrs", "5 d", 
                                 "5 d 8hrs", "5 d 16hrs", "6 d",  
                                 "6 d 8hrs","6 d 16hrs", "7 - 14 d", 
                                 "14 - 21 d", "21 - 28 d", "> 28 d"), 
                         right = FALSE)#
```

with different parameters passed for the 'right' gives me this:

when right = FALSE  I do not get LOS for 61.04 binned for the category ">28 d". BBut do get the right bins for the other ones 2.00 and 3.00.

```
structure(list(IDcol = 101:107, Admissions = structure(c(1539160200, 
1539160200, 1539160200, 1539154800, 1539154800, 1539154800, 1539154800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/London"), 
    Discharges = structure(c(1544434200, 1544434200, 1544434200, 
    1539327600, 1539327600, 1539414000, 1539414000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/London"), Admission_type = c("Elective", 
    "Emergency", "Emergency", "Elective", "Emergency", "Elective", 
    "Emergency"), LOS = c(61.0416666666667, 61.0416666666667, 
    61.0416666666667, 2, 2, 3, 3), Ward_code = c("DSN", "DSN", 
    "DNA", "NAS", "BAS", "BAS", "BAS"), Same_day_discharge = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Spell_type = c("Elective", 
    "Emergency", "Emergency", "Elective", "Emergency", "Elective", 
    "Emergency"), Adm_period = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE), losbinned = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 
    10L, 10L), .Label = c("0hrs", "8hrs", "16hrs", "1 d", "1 d 8hrs", 
    "1 d 16hrs", "2 d", "2 d 8hrs", "2 d 16hrs", "3 d", "3 d 8hrs", 
    "3 d 16hrs", "4 d", "4 d 8hrs", "4 d 16hrs", "5 d", "5 d 8hrs", 
    "5 d 16hrs", "6 d", "6 d 8hrs", "6 d 16hrs", "7 - 14 d", 
    "14 - 21 d", "21 - 28 d", "> 28 d"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

when I pass right = TRUE, the output for 61.04 is binning into ">28 d" which is the desired answer, yet, I do not get the right bins for 2.0 and 3.0, which are  bbinned in 1 d 16hrs for 2.0 and 2 d 16 hrs for 3. And again, these shall be binned in 2, respectively 3.

```
 structure(list(IDcol = 101:107, Admissions = structure(c(1539160200, 
1539160200, 1539160200, 1539154800, 1539154800, 1539154800, 1539154800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/London"), 
    Discharges = structure(c(1544434200, 1544434200, 1544434200, 
    1539327600, 1539327600, 1539414000, 1539414000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/London"), Admission_type = c("Elective", 
    "Emergency", "Emergency", "Elective", "Emergency", "Elective", 
    "Emergency"), LOS = c(61.0416666666667, 61.0416666666667, 
    61.0416666666667, 2, 2, 3, 3), Ward_code = c("DSN", "DSN", 
    "DNA", "NAS", "BAS", "BAS", "BAS"), Same_day_discharge = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Spell_type = c("Elective", 
    "Emergency", "Emergency", "Elective", "Emergency", "Elective", 
    "Emergency"), Adm_period = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE), losbinned = structure(c(25L, 25L, 25L, 6L, 6L, 
    9L, 9L), .Label = c("0hrs", "8hrs", "16hrs", "1 d", "1 d 8hrs", 
    "1 d 16hrs", "2 d", "2 d 8hrs", "2 d 16hrs", "3 d", "3 d 8hrs", 
    "3 d 16hrs", "4 d", "4 d 8hrs", "4 d 16hrs", "5 d", "5 d 8hrs", 
    "5 d 16hrs", "6 d", "6 d 8hrs", "6 d 16hrs", "7 - 14 d", 
    "14 - 21 d", "21 - 28 d", "> 28 d"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The actual and expected results should the the right bins assigned for my length of stay. For 61.04 -> ">28d", for 2 -> "2 d", for 3 -> "3 d".

If this can be done with tidyverse that would be amazing. But respecting the bins I have assigned. However, I am aware this isn't done yet. Therefore, okay with the corrected code I have came up with, but corrected.

Comment: `cut( data , breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 1/3 ) )` bins for hunderd days using a 8hr (=1/3 day ) interval.. apply relevant filtering after binning.

Comment: hello Wimpel, I have tried your suggestion and it does not answer to my question. I hope to find an answer to my problem rather than reproducing something that does not work.

Comment: Add in the include.lowest=TRUE option into the cut statement: `cut(los, breaks=breaks, labels=labels, right=FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)`

Comment: @Dave2e - that worked nice! Is there a way I can thick it as  the right answer if you post it as the answer? In that way others will probably see it as the right way of dealing with such issue.

Comment: Also @GaB you are wrong about your breaks. A difference of 8h in format days will be 8/24 that is 0.333 and not 0.8. The problem is the same for the difference of 16h (0.666 and not 0.16)

Comment: @EtienneKintzler - yes, you're right, yet this is also for visualization purposes. And honestly, after getting the outcome from what Wimpel suggested, as this is where you hint, then I have no clue how to go forward  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cut function's bins are exclusive to inclusive.

From the cut function's help: *The factor level labels are constructed as "(b1, b2]", "(b2, b3]" etc. for right = TRUE and as "[b1, b2)"*

In order to include the lowest value (or highest value in this case), the `include.lowest=TRUE` option in required.  This will make the first bin exclusive to exclusive, "[b1, b2]".

Try:

```
labels<-c("0hrs", "8hrs", "16hrs", "1 d", 
          "1 d 8hrs", "1 d 16hrs", "2 d", 
          "2 d 8hrs", "2 d 16hrs", "3 d", 
          "3 d 8hrs", "3 d 16hrs", "4 d", 
          "4 d 8hrs", "4 d 16hrs", "5 d", 
          "5 d 8hrs", "5 d 16hrs", "6 d",  
          "6 d 8hrs","6 d 16hrs", "7 - 14 d", 
          "14 - 21 d", "21 - 28 d", "> 28 d")

dt_los$losbinned <- cut(los, breaks=breaks, labels=labels, right=FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)
```